# Bleachbit error while runnig as root

Tags: python, kde, bleachbit

I'm getting following 2 errors in bleach bit lately

```
Recent documents list 0 
Error: system.memory: Function: Memory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/bleachbit/Worker.py", line 83, in execute
    for ret in cmd.execute(self.really_delete):
  File "/usr/share/bleachbit/Command.py", line 147, in execute
    for func_ret in self.func():
  File "/usr/share/bleachbit/Memory.py", line 302, in wipe_memory
    wipe_swap_linux(devices, proc_swaps)
  File "/usr/share/bleachbit/Memory.py", line 274, in wipe_swap_linux
    logger.info(_("Wiping the swap device %s."), device)
UnboundLocalError: local variable '_' referenced before assignment
Overwrite free disk space /root/.cache 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug has already been reported and fixed. See [GitHub issue 575](https://github.com/bleachbit/bleachbit/issues/575) or the [patch](https://github.com/bleachbit/bleachbit/commit/b6c108ec04e0a436296971d6a692e3f1517c4a1f)

Comment: how can i fix my bleachbit,do i need to wait for  a new release?

Comment: @A.K. You can wait for the new release, skip the memory cleaning option, or make the edit to Memory.py on your system. The edit is a single character.

Comment: Thank you very much :)